# What does this mean "he was dressed in"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

**We dress in the same clothes every day.**
I understand this, but I cannot understand the below passive structure, what does it mean? Who dresses him in jeans?

**He was dressed in jeans and a thick sweater.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Dressed* is here functioning as an adjective, not a passive verb. It simply doesn't address the question of who dressed him.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to imagine contexts in which "was dressed in" could occur in the quoted sentence as a past-tense passive construction. However, in most cases this sentence would mean simply "he was wearing jeans and a thick sweater," with "dressed" used as an adjective.